# flutter - how to align at the top and at the bottom (this is the issue) - and column middle part

Tags: flutter, alignment

I would like to align a container at the bottom of the widget (given there is containers already at the top and some column in the middle)

So far I can align in at the top followed by some containers using Alignment.topCenter and column.

```
  body: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
```

How can I then put one more container that is right at the bottom of the widget.

reason for this is I want the ad banner to appear at the top and at the bottom. the middle is the real content.

Comment: according to your reputation I would expect better asked question than this. You need to provide more reproducible code then this. perhaps some image of what you're trying to achieve...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Column on top on Align Widget, & add at the bottom of its container with Expanded

```
  Expanded(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            height: 100,  // Give height of banner
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```